# Passing a word into another word

Tags: javascript

How can I pass a word into a specific place within another word?
Lets say I have a string called "apartment"  and I want to pass another string called "blue" after the 3 letter within the string "apartment".  Ex. "apabluertment"

Comment: `var s1='apartment';var s2=s1.slice(0,3)+'blue'+s1.slice(3);`

Answer (score 0):

Try a function like this

```js
function strInPost(src, target, pos) {
  if (pos >= src.length) {
    return src + target;
  }
  if (pos < 0) {
    return target + src;
  }
  return src.slice(0, pos) + target + src.slice(pos);
}

console.log(strInPost('test', 'blue', 9));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var first = "apartment";
var second = "blue";
var position = 3;
console.log([first.slice(0, position), second, first.slice(position)].join(''));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a reusable function that will slice the given word from `3` characters and add the new word accordingly.

```js
function replacement(word, index){
  return word.slice(0,index)+'blue'+word.slice(3);
}

var res = replacement('appartment', 3);
console.log(res);
res = replacement('other', 3);
console.log(res);
```

You can also use the `substring` approach:

```js
function replacement(word, index){
  return word.substr(0,index)+'blue'+word.substr(3, word.length-1);
}

var res = replacement('appartment', 3);
console.log(res);
res = replacement('other', 3);
console.log(res);
```